# Ggplot bar plotting of side by side data not showing as stacked

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to prepare a bar plot comparing the score of two teams against matches (or innings).  I am getting close to what I want.  But the bar chart appears to showing the maximum score in each match and not the total.  Appreciate any advice on how to correct for this.  The data frame I have is

[image: Dataframe used in plotting]

Section of original data:

```
structure(list(batter = c("Ali", "Anderson", "Bairstow", "Ball", 
"Bancroft", "Bird", "Broad", "Cook", "Crane", "Cummins"), team = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Australia", 
"England"), class = "factor"), role = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("allrounder", "batsman", 
"bowler", "wicketkeeper"), class = "factor"), innings = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("test_1_innings_1", 
"test_1_innings_2", "test_2_innings_1", "test_2_innings_2", "test_3_innings_1", 
"test_3_innings_2", "test_4_innings_1", "test_4_innings_2", "test_5_innings_1", 
"test_5_innings_2"), class = "factor"), batting_num = c(6, 11, 
7, 10, 1, NA, 9, 1, NA, 9), score = c(38, 5, 9, 14, 5, NA, 20, 
2, NA, 42), balls_faced = c(102, 9, 24, 11, 19, NA, 32, 10, NA, 
120)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The graph that I have developed so far (which as noted above is incorrect) and shows maximum individual score and not the total team score is as follows:

[image: Plot so far]

The code for doing this is as follows:

```
plot_graphs <- function(){
        ashes_df <- tidy_data() #imports data frame
        
        canvas2 <- ggplot(ashes_df,aes(x = innings, y = score, fill = team))
        graph2 <- canvas2 +
                geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
                ggtitle("England & Australia Innings Scores") +
                theme_bw()
                
        print(graph2)
}
```

Any help would certainly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

summarise the data first before plotting.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ashes_df %>%
  group_by(innings, team) %>%
  summarise(batting_num = sum(batting_num, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = innings, y = batting_num, fill = team)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", na.rm = TRUE) +
  ggtitle("England & Australia Innings Scores") +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks and sorry for the delayed response